# Fail to fine-tuned VGG pytorch with DataLoader

Tags: pytorch, dataloader

I try to replicate estimation of poverty based on satellite images from this github repo: https://github.com/jmather625/predicting-poverty-replication

I try to use Pytorch VGG on satellite images dataset. My inputs (X) are daytime satellite images and my desire output are categories of nightlights [0,1,2]. Categories have been built based on nightlights satellites images.

Unfortunately, i fail to start training because of the following error:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

model_ft, hist = train_model(model_ft, dataloaders_dict, criterion, optimizer_ft, num_epochs=1)
File "C:\Users\Franck\anaconda3\envs\pop_env\lib\site-packages\PIL\_binary.py", line 85, in i32be
    return unpack_from(">I", c, o)[0]
struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes for unpacking 4 bytes at offset 0 (actual buffer size is 0)
```

It seems like it is related to the dataloader.